# how to generate a network graph with edge weight using D3.js force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I read many codes about force layout with D3.js and I found that edges elements are only 'source' and 'target'. I want to generate a graph whose layout is like the 'Altas' in Gephi. In my data, edge has elements of 'weight', which describe the correlation of nodes it links, and this is supposed to be took into consideration when start the force layout. So that the similar nodes can gather together. Is there a way to implement so or the physics model used in force layout is irrelevant with the weight of edges?

Comment: It would be nice that you tell the community whether a solution works or not. Maybe, someone else has the same question like you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is possible in D3.js, however, I recommend the *webcola* library since it is more easy and faster and works very well with D3.js.

Each edge may contain other information besides `source` and `target`. So, it is easy to add a `weight` attribute, e.g.:

```
let edge = {
  source: node1,
  target: node2,
  weight: 2
};
```

When using *webcola* (https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola/), you can add some constraints to use your weights, or you can use the `linkDistance` as a function, explained here: https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola/wiki/link-lengths, e.g.:

```
let weightFactor = 10;
let d3cola = cola.d3adaptor(d3)
                   .size([500, 400])
                   .linkDistance(function (l) { return l.weight * weightFactor; };
```

So, the steps are:

1. Build your graph with D3.js, however,
2. Simulate it with *webcola*

You can create an instance of a webcola simulation for d3.js like that:

```
d3cola.avoidOverlaps(true)
      .handleDisconnected(false)
      .start(30);

let simulation = this.d3cola
    .nodes(graph.nodes) // graph is your graph
    .links(graph.edges)
    .start();
```

Comment: I'm pleased that my solution had helped.